# Change width of element without reflow

Tags: javascript, css, reflow

I have a music player with an animated bar that displays the current position in the song. It is rendered with `requestAnimationFrame` and works by changing the `width` style of the div to X%, where X is the percentage of time through the current song.

This causes huge CPU use in Chrome I believe due to the constant reflow work being done each frame. What are other options I can use to eliminate reflows and reduce CPU?

Two other requirements: this web page is a web UI over a back end music server. It's not using any HTML5 media elements. As such, the page may be loaded when the song is already partially over, so the position will not always animate between 0 and 100.

The below fiddle shows up at about 30% CPU on my machine, which seems a bit high to animate a rectangle.

```js
var pos = 0;
var s = document.getElementById('i');
f = function() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(f);
  pos += .03;
  s.style.width = pos + '%';
}
f();
```

```css
#i {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="i">&nbsp;
</div>
```

Comment: Why `setAttribute`? Just use `s.style.width =  pos + '%';`

Comment: @Oriol changed to that; doesn't help any

Comment: @RayonDabre because I'm unaware of another way.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of ways you could make a pure CSS progress bar that won’t cause a relayout, here are a few examples:

1. **`animation`** - http://jsbin.com/yoqabe/edit?html,css,js,output

   I think one of the most performant ways would be to use an animation to control the background position of a linear-gradient. The only downside is that you can only play/pause the animation.
2. **`background-position`** - http://jsbin.com/veyibe/edit?html,css,js,output

   If you need the ability to update the position with JS, then I would suggest updating the `background-position` of a gradient and applying CSS transitions, debouncing to avoid updating too quickly.
3. **`translateX`:** http://jsbin.com/zolurun/edit?html,js,output

   You could also use CSS transforms to slide the progress bar inside of a container, which should also avoid a repaint.

These links might also be useful:

- List of CSS layout, paint, and composite triggers: http://csstriggers.com
- Debounce info: https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using other CSS properties which don't require layout opearations, such as `background-size`.

And use CSS animations instead of `requestAnimationFrame`.

```js
var bar = document.getElementById('i');
function playSong(currentTime, duration) {
  bar.style.animationDuration = duration + 's';
  bar.style.animationDelay = - currentTime + 's';
}
playSong(3, 10);
```

```css
#i {
  height: 1em;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, red);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  animation: bar linear;
}
@keyframes bar {
  from { background-size: 0% 100%; }
  to { background-size: 100% 100%; }
}
```

```html
<div id="i"></div>
```

Comment: What if a song is already half done? I need the bar to start at 50%, not go from 0 to 100 in half the time. (The song is not playing from the tab, the tab is just a UI over a music server.)

Comment: @mjibson You can use animation properties to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `position: absolute` or `position: fixed` on the progress bar itself, it should prevent large reflows on the page.

Comment: Then there must be something else running on your page that's causing it.  What JS are you running?  I have a feeling you have something intensive in your JS that is causing the lag you're experiencing and not simply the element resizing itself.

Answer (score 0):

> Use [`timeupdate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/timeupdate), The time indicated by the element's currentTime attribute has changed.

Try this:

```js
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");

function updateProgress() {
  var progress = document.getElementById("progress");
  var value = 0;
  if (audio.currentTime > 0) {
    value = Math.ceil((100 / audio.duration) * audio.currentTime);
  }
  progress.style.width = value + "%";
}


audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", updateProgress, false);
```

```css
#progressBar {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  color: #fff;
  width: 295px;
  height: 20px;
}
#progress {
  background-color: #ff0000; // red
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="progressBar"><span id="progress"></span>
</div>
<audio id="audio" controls>
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: `timeupdate` only works on HTML5 audio elements, which my thing is not. The web page is a UI over a backend music server.

Answer (score 0):

The script you present is not very relevant to the one you desire, you animate on `requestAnimationFrame` but in reality you will animate every time the "song percentage" changes.

Assuming that you have a function (e.g. `getSongPer()`)  that returns the current percentage of played song:

```
var oldPos, pos = 0;
var s = document.getElementById('i');
f = function() {
  oldPos = pos;
  pos = getSongPer();
  if(oldPos !== pos){
    s.style.width = pos + '%';
  }
  if(pos<100){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(f);
  }
}
f();
```

I didn't test it, but I expect it to be lighter, also, the performance will be affected by the precision of the percentage, e.g. there will be about 100 animation changes if you have zero digit precision and around ten times more for every digit after.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
#progress-bar {
  background-color: red;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

JS:

```
'use strict'

var progressBar = document.getElementById('progress-bar')

function setProgress(percentage) {
  requestAnimationFrame(function () {
    progressBar.style.transform = 'scaleX(' + percentage + '%)'
  })
}

setProgress(10)
```

When setting the width to 100% you get a full width colored bar.

Then we can apply the scale transform to set the width of the bar without reflowing.

But oh, it scales to the middle. We can fix that by setting the origin of the transform to the top left corner using `transform-origin: x y`, with x and y being 0.

Then we wrap the style change in requestAnimationFrame to let the browser optimize when to apply the change.

Bam! You have a performant zero reflow progress bar.

Comment: You should provide more information with your answer. Perhaps an explanation of what you are doing. Simply posting the answer will cause your post to be down voted, or deleted.

Comment: @Chris Better? :)